# Section hover active and inactive by CSS3

Tags: html, css

I am making a pricing table by html and css3 . But facing problem to deactivate the active hover section when i hover non active sections.

Preview: http://goo.gl/1KHzC6

In the preview website there is a featured section name "standard" and its -15px top to highlight properly but i want to make it 0px from top when i hover other sections. As well as when i do not hover any sections the "standard" sections remain -15px top. Please help me out.

Comment: Post you relevant code and even better if you can make a fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cheat by using `:hover` behaviours on the parent container.

HTML for example:

```
<main>
    <div></div>
    <div class="default"></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</main>
```

Short CSS for example:

```
div {
    position:relative;
    top:15px;
    transition:top 500ms;
}
div:hover, div.default {
    top:0;
}
main:hover div.default:not(:hover) {
    top:15px;
}
```

The last rule resets the position of the default element if the container is hovered but the default element isn't - so it must be over another of the prices.

[Sample fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Curry/hmu2xw4v/).